# Resources-Route with nested GET breaks Resource-Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Running Rails 3.2.11, I have a regular controller "LbuController" which is basically an enhanced scaffold, enhanced by 4 additional GET methods used for AJAX requests.

```
resources :lbus do
  get 'add_offering'
  get 'remove_offering'
  get 'add_offering_element'
  get 'remove_offering_element'
end
```

running `rake routes` gives me the following routes

```
           lbu_add_offering GET    /lbus/:lbu_id/add_offering(.:format)                                 lbus#add_offering
        lbu_remove_offering GET    /lbus/:lbu_id/remove_offering(.:format)                              lbus#remove_offering
   lbu_add_offering_element GET    /lbus/:lbu_id/add_offering_element(.:format)                         lbus#add_offering_element
lbu_remove_offering_element GET    /lbus/:lbu_id/remove_offering_element(.:format)                      lbus#remove_offering_element
                       lbus GET    /lbus(.:format)                                                      lbus#index
                            POST   /lbus(.:format)                                                      lbus#create
                    new_lbu GET    /lbus/new(.:format)                                                  lbus#new
                   edit_lbu GET    /lbus/:id/edit(.:format)                                             lbus#edit
                        lbu GET    /lbus/:id(.:format)                                                  lbus#show
                            PUT    /lbus/:id(.:format)                                                  lbus#update
                            DELETE /lbus/:id(.:format)                                                  lbus#destroy
```

which seem exactly to be what I intended.

But following a link to `http://localhost:3000/lbus/new` created with `link_to "new", new_lbu_path` gives me the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"add_offering", :lbu_id=>nil, :offering_id=>1, :controller=>"lbus"}
```

which makes absolutely no sense for me.
Anybody got any ideas what's happening here and what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that the error is related to the new action. But it refers to add_offering -> is there an error in either the controller action of new or the view you are redirected to after clicking "new"?

Comment: @Oliver on the 'new' view you must have used a lbu_add_offering path. That path seems to be incorrect. The error refers to that :action=> "add_offering"

Comment: No, it must be a routing related issue. As soon as I remove the block with the `get` methods the `new` action works as expected.

Comment: @Nishant - you are correct. That's the case! Thank you

Comment: @Oliver Happy to help. I have converted that to an answer - which you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 'new' view you must have used a lbu_add_offering path.

That path seems to be incorrect. The error refers to that :action=> "add_offering".